# javascript spin wheel 'prize' selection based on percentage

Tags: javascript

I have created a spin wheel using the code below

```
<script>
var spinWheel = new Winwheel({
    'numSegments' : 4,
    'segments'    :
    [
        {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 1'},
        {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 2'},
        {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 3'},
        {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 4'}
    ]
});
```

I'm using this JS library
http://dougtesting.net/winwheel/examples/basic_code_wheel

What I want to do is to create a function that will let me be more in control of the result after the 'wheel' has spun? If you have a solution or can point me to an existing script I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean. Can you [edit] your question and provide specific examples, along with what you’ve tried and what didn’t work?

Comment: Also, if you are using any library, please tag it. That will bring question to correct group and your issue will be resolved sooner

Answer (score 1):

A quick run through the code suggests that the stop angle can either be hardcoded or it is chosen at random.

To hardcode it, you need to set the property `stopAngle` while initializing `winwheel`. If you do that, it always stops at that angle. So you need to reinitialize `winwheel` everytime or, go into the source of the plugin to add your own method to set the angle.

Now for the problem of setting weighted probabilities to each segment, you can do it in any way that skews probability in favour of the segment that you want. One example might be, to assign numbers from 1 to 100 to each segment like, segment 1 gets 1 to 50 (50%), segment 2 gets 51 to 60(10%) ... Then get a random number between 1 to 100 and choose the segment appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Vj-, there is the ability to control the result of the spin, and this is done by setting the stopAngle of the animation before the spinning starts.

This tutorial http://dougtesting.net/winwheel/docs/tut14_setting_the_prize details 2 ways of doing this.

The first is calculating this in some JavaScript code on the page, the other - and more secure way - is having a server side process calculate this and return the number of the prize to be won by the user. The server side process could also do things like updating a database to record the prize won etc.

Also as Vj- says, a quick and easy way to make a selection based on percentage is to pick a random number between 1 and 100 and then depending on the number selecting the segment. If segment 1 should be won 50% of the time, then if the number is between 1 and 50 segment 1 is selected.

If segment 2 should be won 25% of the time then if the random number is between 51 and 75 segment 2 is selected as the winner and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

@matt z, there is a **winwheelPercentToDegrees** private class inside **Winwheels.js**, the developer left it there.

I used it to convert % into actual degrees.  But I did a bit of customization to the source code.

Basically there are two places I had to modify to get the segments in percentage to work

1. Segments parameters

```
'segments'     :        // Define segments including colour and text.
               [
                  {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 1', 'percentage': 40},
                  {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 2', 'percentage': 20},
                  {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 3', 'percentage': 20},
                  {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 4', 'percentage': 20}
               ],
```

need to include the percentage for each prizes

1. add **winwheelPercentToDegrees** in line 277 - 289

```
for (let x = 1; x <= this.numSegments; x ++) {
            //TODO calcuate degrees based on percentages
            // Set start angle.
            this.segments[x].startAngle = currentDegree;

            // If the size is set then add this to the current degree to get the end, else add the degreesEach to it.
            if (this.segments[x].size) {
                currentDegree += this.segments[x].size;
            } else if(this.segments[x].percentage) {
                currentDegree += winwheelPercentToDegrees(this.segments[x].percentage);
            } else {
                currentDegree += degreesEach;
            }

            // Set end angle.
            this.segments[x].endAngle = currentDegree;
        }
```

Basically you need to check when the percentage param is present, we need to translate that to degrees.

If you modify these two places, it will draw a circle with the defined percentages.

It's been 6 years since you asked this question.  Hope it helps!

and thank you @dougtesting.net for creating this awesome library!